# Flutter : I have NULL in my variable , How to use my function?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  String tmpimage;

  Uint8List TmpBytesImage;
  File pimage;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      TmpBytesImage= profileimage();
    });
  }

  profileimage() async {
    var userimage1 = await DBHelper().getuserIMAGE1('roro');
    print(userimage1);
    if (userimage1 == Null) {
      print('Empty');
    } else {
      setState(() {
        userimage1.map((e) {
          tmpimage = e['image0'];
        }).toList();
        print(tmpimage);
        return Base64Decoder().convert(tmpimage);
      });
    }
  }
```

The first error was:

> Only static members can be accessed in initializers

I added :

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      TmpBytesImage= profileimage();
    });
  }
```

Then it seemed to be working normally.

But there is a `null` value in the `TmpBytesImage`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you were not awaiting on your future method. Just replace your `initState` with this:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async{
    TmpBytesImage = await profileimage();
  });
}
```

Comment: still Null,,,,,

Comment: Can you tell me what `print(userimage1);` is printing on console?

Comment: when I use ```print(userimage1);```, it's NULL on the console.

Comment: Which actually means there is something your database returns you `null`, and you return this `null` to your `TmpBytesImage`, so there is no problem in above solution, all you need to do is debug your app and check why database is returning null for `roro`

Comment: In the ```profileimage()``` , it contains values, but ```onTap:()
print(userimage1);```
  is not contained in it.